# Displaying username of the two user_id's in sql

Tags: mysql

How to show the username of another user_id?

```
$sql= "Select order.order_id,user.user_id , user.username as added, user.user_id2 as Edited 
from order left join user on order.user_id= user.user_id";

My php:
echo $row['added'];
echo $row['Edited'];  //but I can only display the id.
```

I want to display the username of the user Id to the one who updated the order. 
I was able to display the username of the one who added but I can't display the username of the one who updated, rather I can only display the user_id of the one who updated the order.

Expected Output:

```
Added by: user_id=18 Username: James
Edited by: user_id=15 Username: Matt
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do multi-join:

```
Select o.order_id,o.user_id as added_userid,u1.username as added_username,o.user_id2 as edited_userid,u2.username as edited_username 
from order o left join user u1 on o.user_id = u1.user_id 
left join user u2 on o.user_id2 = u2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not select the Edit username in your SQL statement:

```
$sql= "Select order.order_id,user.user_id , user.username as added,user.user_id2, user.username2 as Edited
from order left join user on order.user_id= user.user_id";
```

That should do it!

Comment: I got this error  Unknown column 'user.username2' in 'field list'